# Searching Query in solr using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, solrcloud

I configured the solr Search server in Tomcat server. I started tomcat server with below extra parameters.

```
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9191
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Now I wants to test solr Searching request in my JMeter for load testing purpose. Will I be able to do it in Jmeter?

Comment: Why don't you just give it a try? It won't hurt, if you are not experimenting on a production server.

Comment: I tried with HTTP Request but not success. So, I would like to know any other way by which I can achieve this.                                                  Thanks

Comment: Then you should edit and rephrase you question so that it reflects your actual issue and the steps you attempted. It currently looks [too broad and unclear](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14769959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Solr Quick Start](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html)

> Searching
>
> Solr can be queried via REST clients, cURL, wget, Chrome POSTMAN, etc., as well as via the native clients available for many programming languages.
>
> The Solr Admin UI includes a query builder interface - see the gettingstarted query tab at http://localhost:8983/solr/#/gettingstarted/query.

So you should be able to perform a search using HTTP Request sampler

[image: JMeter Solr Request]

Replace `gettingstarted` with your Solr core name and `YOUR_QUERY_HERE` with your actual query.

You will also be able to use [XPath or JSON Path Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) in order to extract some response parts into JMeter Variables if needed